# Sqlite3 error while creating a simple table Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am writing a simple program:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('temp.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks(date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This gives me "OperationalError: disk I/O error" did anyone face similar issue?

Comment: The error says that you could not read or write a disk file. It may happen if you execute your script in a non writable directory.

Comment: conn = sqlite3.connect('temp.db') creates a file so I confused how this could be a non writable directory